# During debugging of python code how can we see the values of variables in python classes

Tags: python, class, oop

This is my code:

```
class starter:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.__table_name = file_name
        self.__path = dirname(dirname(realpath(__file__)))
        self.__file_config.log['Folder'] = self.__path+self.__file_config.log['Folder']
        self.__logging = self.__file_config.log
   def start_script(self,fl_name):
        try:
            self.__logging.info("Script Started")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if not (starter("samplefile").start_script(str(os.path.basename(__file__)))):
            raise Exception ('error')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When debugging the `start_script` function, I want  to check the value of `self.__logging`.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: set a break point at the line `self.__logging.info("Script Started")` then inspect the self and its associated attributes like __logging

Comment: Note that you might need to look for the _mangled name_ of the variable because you have prefixed the its name with two underscore characters. See [**private name mangling**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) in the docs. In this case it would be `_starter__logging`.

Comment: I tried this, but am getting error  NameError: name '__logging' is not defined

Comment: NameError: name '_starter__logging' is not defined am getting same error @martineau

Comment: The full name would be `self._starter__logging` in the context of a class method. You could also try removing the `__` prefix from the attribute's name.

Comment: The name mangling is probably doing more harm than good. Consider using regular attribute names like `table_name` instead of `__table_name` or even `_table_name`.

Comment: @chepner Can you exactly tell me how it is doing harm...I am so new to this private variables concept. I am just debugging code that was created by someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use p self._starter__logging.info

-> self.start_script("args")
(Pdb) p self._starter__logging

__variable name is user defined private variable

example:-

> > > class Box:
> > >       ...     **var=10
> > >       ...
> > >       dir(Box)
> > >       ['_Box__var', '__class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**fo
> > >       rmat**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**
> > >       ', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '_
> > >       _repr__', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**']
> > >
> > > dir(Box)[0]
> > >       '_Box__var'